# Slice subclassed pandas series returns full data when custom method is applied

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, slice, subclass

So for some reason I want to subclass a pandas.Series like so:

```
class _Subseries(pd.Series):
   
   _metadata = ['custom_method']
   
   @property
   def _constructor(self):
       return _Subseries
   
   @property
   def _constructor_expanddim(self):
       return _Subseries
   
   def custom_method(self, value):
       return self.values + value
```

I make an instance, slice it, and check that the type is unchanged:

```
s = _Subseries(range(5))
s = s[-3:]
print(s.values, type(s[-2:]))
```

[2 3 4] <class '**main**._Subseries'>

So far so good. The series seems sliced as it should and the type has remained unchanged.

Now, if I want to apply some method on this object, it will not apply it on the sliced version, but on the original one:

```
s.custom_method(1)
```

array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=int64)

Questions:

- Is this normal behaviour?
- If not, how can I subclass a pandas.Series, slice it, apply a method to it, and make it return the result of that method on the sliced data (instead of the original data as is the case here), without changing the type?

Extra info:

- pandas 1.1.3
- python 3.7.9

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Only attributes need to be defined in `_metadata` to be accessible after, for example, slicing. Removing `custom_method` from `_metadata` will return the expected result when executing `s.custom_method(1)`:

array([3, 4, 5], dtype=int64)

Explanation:

Attributes defined in `_metadata` are copied from the original instance, i.e. in this case `s_sliced.custom_method = s.custom_method` which results in the different shape observed in the posted question.